# How accounts, wallets and addresses are related

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, litecoin

I have downloaded litecoin code (version of 14 september,2014) and built it. so right now I have a wallet. i have account which's name is just "". then i connected my miner to my node. It solved the block and now I have a balance. ./litecoin-cli getbalance "" returns 150LTC , but as I can see, there're 3 addresses which belong to this account (""); why all of these 3 addresses have balance 0.000? how is it possible that account has a balance and not the addresses? Even if i type ./litecoin-cli getinfo it tells me that my balance is 0.0000 , but if i type ./litecoin-cli getbalance "" why does it return 150?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you mine a block and get the block reward (50 LTC in your case), the coins are not spendable immediately. There is a maturity period of 100 blocks before you can spend them. I believe this is why they don't show up.

Comment: I'll explain the situation. I had built litecoin source code then run the daemon. Miner was solving the blocks, but balance was actually always 0.000 when writing ./litecoin-cli getinfo , but always 1600 as I have 32 blocks and each reward is 50 - when writing ./litecoin-cli getbalance "".  That was it before I decided to trust you. so By trusting you, I changed Maturity from 100 to 2. And run the daemon again. when that happened, i write ./litecoin-cli getinfo and it showed the balance like 800, and didn't show the whole balance(1600) at all. Why do you think this could happen? Thanks

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze I can't think of anything else that might affect it.